# RegExp match arbitrary string + 8 digits

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to match urls in the format of arbitrary string + dash + 8 digits:

```
yellow-purse-65788544
big-yellow-purse-66784500
iphone-smart-case-water-resistant-55006610
```

I've built this this one, but it doesn't work:

```
new RegExp(/^[a-z][A-Z]-\d{8}$/).test('big-yellow-purse-66784500'); // false
```

Can you help me fix my broken RegExp?

Comment: `-` needs to be `\-`

Comment: @dandavis Still doesn't work. new RegExp(/^[a-z][A-Z]\-\d{8}$/).test('big-yellow-purse-66784500');

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z\-]+-\d{8}$/`, and don't pass it to RegExp() either, no need and will break stuff

Comment: @dandavis Woop woop! Please post as an answer so I can approve it. Thanks.

Comment: well, @Ad.Infinitum says it pretty well, go ahead and accepts his since he needs it

Comment: @timolawl The question is "arbitrary string + dash + 8 digits" meaning basically `^.+-\d{8}$` would be good enough since "arbitrary string" could be absolutely anything.

Comment: @Bikonja I don't think the author intends for it to be completely arbitrary given his regex attempt and examples. Without the author here to verify, we can only speculate. I've taken the stance that I believe the author intends for a specifically formatted string given his examples, but others like yourself can take his "arbitrary" label literally. Point taken about my comment though. I'll remove it. If I am correct, then the other answers will not rule out false positives, which my answer does. If I'm wrong, then I've added unnecessary specificity, resulting in an improper solution.

Comment: The string is not completely arbitrary. It would be lowercase dashed alpha numeric.

Comment: @ChrisRch As I expected. I've updated my answer to your exact use case (by removing the uppercase matching and adding in number matching). It should serve your use case perfectly without matching false positives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The string is not completely arbitrary. It would be lowercase dashed alpha numeric.

You can use the following regex, which rules out a list of false positives that other answers do not account for (detailed in the Regex101):

```
^(?:[a-z0-9]+-)+\d{8}$
```

**[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kD5mL1/8)**

Example construction:

```js
document.body.textContent = /^(?:[a-z0-9]+-)+\d{8}$/.test('big-yellow-purse-66784500');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^([a-zA-Z]*-)+\d{8}$/.test("iphone-smart-case-water-resistant-55006610");
```

Answer (score 0):

You string has **several dashes** (**-**) but the regex just have the **last one**, try this:

```
/^[a-z-]+-\d{8}$/im
```

---

**Regex101 Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/rT7xT0/1

---

**Regex explanation:**

```
/^[a-z-]+-\d{8}$/im

    ^ assert position at start of a line
    [a-z-]+ match a single character present in the list below
        Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case insensitive)
        - the literal character -
    - matches the character - literally
    \d{8} match a digit [0-9]
        Quantifier: {8} Exactly 8 times
    $ assert position at end of a line
    i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])
    m modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
```

---

**Demo:**

```js
stringOne = "iphone-smart-case-water-resistant-55006610";
stringtwo = "big-yellow-purse-66784500";
stringThree = "iphone-smart-case-water-resistant-55006610222222";
var myregexp = /^[a-z-]+-\d{8}$/im;

if(myregexp.test(stringOne)){
  document.write(stringOne + " - TRUE<br>"); 
}else{
  document.write(stringOne + " - FALSE<br>"); 
}

if(myregexp.test(stringtwo)){
  document.write(stringtwo + " - TRUE<br>"); 
}else{
  document.write(stringtwo + " - FALSE<br>"); 
}

if(myregexp.test(stringThree)){
  document.write(stringThree + " - TRUE<br>"); 
}else{
  document.write(stringThree + " - FALSE<br>"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string really can be arbitrary, you can use this:

```
/^.*?-\d{8}$/i
```

The `.+?` is a non-greedy match for any characters, and `\d{8}` says to match exactly 8 digits.

Alternatively, you could use:

```
/^[\w-]+?-\d{8}$/i
```

This matches any number of "word" or '-' characters, followed by a '-' and 8 digits.

These both also match the case commonly seen with human-readable URLs in which there are multiple '-' characters in sequence, which can happen by converting something like "Dollar $ign money clip" to "dollar--ign-money clip".